# Accessing results of JavaScript's "window.confirm" in regular Java

Tags: java, javascript

I have a Java page that uses embedded JavaScript to create a confirmation message (I'm using window.confirm). I would like to use the results of the user's selection (either "Yes" or "No") outside of that JavaScript snippet but I'm not sure how. To clarify, I know how to check the user's selection in JavaScript but I am trying to pass that along to rest of the page, which is written in Java.

Supose I saved that result in a hidden field on the client side and wanted to pass that value as an argument back to the server to be used in Java. Would that be possible? And if, so, what is the correct synthex to access the value of that hidden field or other intermediary object?

UPDATE: The decision is to whether or not I want to save a record to a database. Clicking on the Save button brings up the Confirmation box (written in JavaScript) and also triggers a postback triggering and within a DoGet event that follows I would like to be able to tell what the result was so that I can know whether or not to proceed with saving.

There may be a delay in my future responses.

UPDATE #2: **I was able to find a solution**. To prevent the postback from happening after clicking the "No" button. I just needed to add:

```
{ event.returnValue = false; return false; } // simply using return false by itself didn't help
```

[This page](http://delroger.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/postback-occurring-after-cancel-clicked/) really helped:

Comment: What decision are you making based on the confirm? What syntax do you need in order to access that value, the javascript or the java?

Comment: Thaks, for the responses. I have updated my question.

Comment: Have the OK result do a postback and dont postback if they hit cancel.

Comment: The thing is that unless I am missing something (and if I do please correct me) the postback will happen anyway, since everytime the Save button click it will trigger both the Java script event and a Java event that inside of DoGet.

Comment: For your own edification, the term is syntax, not synthex or synthax.

Comment: Typos happen when you're in a hurry. Still, I will derive my own edification from knowing something about you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can dynamically add a `<input type="hidden" name="yes"/>` tag to a form and then let the user submit the form when ready.

Or you can use Ajax--which also has the advantage of being able to work asynchronously (without necessitating an entire page refresh).

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about reading that information from the form using regular Java? That is the part I am having difficulty with as I don't knwo the correct synthax.

Comment: I will try returng false to prevent postback.

Comment: I tried using "return false;" to my else case but it didn't prevent the postback, probably due t the reasons stated above.

Comment: I was able to find a solution. To prevent the postback from happening after clicking the "No" button. I just needed to add:

{ event.returnValue = false; return false; } // simply using return false by itself didn't help